# How to disable other joystick buttons while one of them is being clicked Angular ngx Gamepad

Tags: angular, typescript, joystick, gamepad, gamepad-api

Basically what I need is to block other joystick buttons while one is clicked.

Currently, by clicking two buttons, both perform the action at the same time or one by one. I want to avoid the situation of 'queuing' actions assigned to individual buttons when one is clicked.

Expectations: when one button is clicked, the other buttons do not trigger an action, even when released. If two buttons are clicked at the same time, and the simultaneous click combination has not been assigned, I don't want to trigger any action.
Clicking the correct button alone triggers an action.

I'm open to changing the joystick event handling library for Angular if it can implement the above requirements.